# Latex: How to ignore modifications of chapter headings in appendix?

Tags: sectioning, chapters, appendix

I am writing in a document with this class:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,openright]{report}
```

I have made the following modification to the chapter headings:

```
\makeatletter
\def\@makechapterhead#1{%
  \vspace*{50\p@}%
  {\parindent \z@ \raggedright \normalfont
    \interlinepenalty\@M
    \Huge\bfseries  \thechapter.\quad #1\par\nobreak
    \vskip 40\p@
  }}
\makeatother

\makeatletter
\renewcommand\chapter{\if@openright\cleardoublepage\else\clearpage\fi
                    \thispagestyle{empty}%
                    \global\@topnum\z@
                    \@afterindentfalse
                    \secdef\@chapter\@schapter}
\makeatother
```

But this also affects the appendix titles such that it is just called:

**A. Appendix Title**

Instead of the original, when using \appendix:

**Appendix A**

**Appendix Title**

Can Anyone help with a way to ignore the modifications in the appendix so it looks like it does "normally"?

Comment: this is unrelated to overleaf, that's just where you are running latex

Comment: You could copy the original definitions from `report.cls` into the `\appendix` definition. Or use a class, that provides the wanted as feature, e.g., use class `scrreprt` with option `appendixprefix` instead of class `report`. Or use a package like `titlesec` to modify the `\chapter` for the main part and once again for the appendix. Or … there are a lot of possibilities, depending on what you really use. So a [minimal working example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/277964), that also shows already used packages related to section/chapter headings, would be useful—as usual.

Comment: One can use things like `\let\appendixhead=\@makechapterhead` early then use `\let\@makechapterhead=\appendixhead` to restore the original definition.